# How to change bundle resources on-the-fly in bndtools / felix environment

Tags: osgi, on-the-fly, bndtools

During development we need to change content of particular file in bundle and be able to see changed file content in application without recompiling / rebundling / bundle reinstalling. File is read by `Bundle.getEntry()` every time the application needs its content.

Using Eclipse PDE and Equinox it is quit simple, because OSGi framework launched from Eclipse environment treats project folders as unpacked bundles. Changes in files in project folder are reflected every time the application reads resource content.

If I understand it correctly, bndtools always repackages bundle when change in resource is detected. But for project with hundreds of resource files it takes too much time. Is it possible to achieve similar behavior as in Eclipse PDE? Preferably in Apache Felix? We need such functionality only during development / debugging and only if application is launched from IDE. Resources will never be changed in production.

To be concrete - in our application there is lot of LESS files that are compiled to several CSS. CSS are generated immediately after any of LESS files changes. This is achieved by gulp and node.js. We need to see changed CSS files (almost) immediately when page is reloaded. Note that we are not using OSGi HTTP service.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible.

If the Bndtools packaging is taking too long it may be an indication that your bundle is too big and you should try to modularise more.

Comment: Suppose that we rearrange our bundles to take less time to package. Still - is there an option for "bundle hot replace" - i.e. running application will access changed files without re-installing the bundle?

Comment: If you launch inside Bndtools then yes this is the default. Bundles are hot-updated every time they change.

Answer (score 0):

I've some applications where I develop with resources in bundles and that works fine. (See [OSGi enRoute](http://enroute.osgi.org) that uses this model.) As long as bundles are not that large they built in sub-second time. So the best advise is to see if you can break up your code/resources in multiple modules that are smaller. The smaller, the quicker it builds.

If this is really a problem, and I would see this as a bit of a desperate attempt, you could of course change the code that calls `getEntry` to also look at the file system. In development mode (set via config admin), you could then fetch it from there.